# Problem running .NET Core Azure functions on Visual Studio Code. Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am getting following error in visual studio code while running brand new Azure function project created newly.

It's roughly about .NET Core Sdk and all other errors seems to be relate with that. Can somebody help me to get rid from them.

I already tested all other links but my problem is not related with the any of the described issues.
[image]

**CSProjFile**

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image: While do]

Comment: What's the target runtime of your application (as seen in the csproj file)? I bet it's .Net 6, and you don't have that SDK installed.

Comment: TargetFramework is net 6.0

Comment: Please stop adding text to your post as images. Add text as text.

Comment: Okay, I'll remove these pics but i thought it clearly indicate the issue while reading the text and further explanation might ends up more stress.
Can I have the clue where the problem is?

Comment: If you need/want to use .NET 6, make sure you're using Visual Studio 2022, and have the .NET 6 SDK installed (get it here -> https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0), or target a lower framework supported by your current setup.

Comment: Re: text over images -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Venator : I am working with Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio. I already installed  SDK 6.0.101, but in visual studio code it still complains about these errors.

Comment: You absolutely DO NOT have .Net SDK 6.0.101 installed, it's very clearly missing from the output of the dotnet --list-sdks command you've provided.

Comment: .NET 6 is supported with the Visual Studio Code C# extension => https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp

Comment: Okay, Sorry Installed .NET Core 6.0.101 and got other issues.
for example (error NU1102: Unable to find package System.Runtime with version (>= 5.0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have .Net SDK `6.0.100` along with `6.0.101` as you can see below:

[image]

And Created the **Azure Functions** of Stack **.Net 6.0 Http Trigger Function** through Visual Studio Code, it is running successfully.

[image]

Here is my `.csproj` file:

[image]

As I believe that you're missing the `SDK Package Reference` in the ItemGroup of your `.csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions"  Version="4.0.1"  />
```

Include it in the `.csproj` file and check running the function.