# Azure Function extension for VS Code throwing error when trying to create the function app in Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-extensions

When I get to [this section in this MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process#publish-the-project-to-azure) and I give a name, select location, etc. and I press enter to start to build it function app, I see this error message and the function app fails to get created.
[image]

**QUESTION** - Does anyone know how to diagnose this or why this is happening?

FYI - I'm using the latest Azure Functions extension version 1.7.3. I also tried restarting VS Code, logging out and back into Azure within VS Code, uninstalling then reinstalling the extension but nothing worked. I also tried going back to version 1.5 from 6 months ago and trying, but still received the same error message.

Comment: strange that you mention 1.7.3, You should be using Azure Functions runtime version 4.x, [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=azure-cli%2Cin-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: could you please check few of my threads which helps you about the clear information from creation to running the Azure Functions C# Http Trigger using VS Code. [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72722858/16630138), [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71187198/16630138), [Thread3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70777870/16630138)

Comment: Hi Anand. Sorry, I was wrong. I am running v4 for the Azure function core tools. My Azure function extension is 1.1.0 (latest). I was able to create a function app and a new function using the command line. I haven't circled back to see if I can get it created using the IDE extension

Comment: Hello @user1186050, is this issue resolved?

Comment: Not from me, it's not. But I was able to create a function project and function using the cli without any errors. So I've moved on.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still faces a similar issue. Please make sure you have [configured the environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process#configure-your-environment) and it is installed correctly. In case if you still observe the issue then please create a support ticket so we can look into your environment setup. If you don't have a support plan then please let me know so I can assist you further.